How to check the existence of related records in group by query?
There are 3 simple tables Orders, OrderLines and OrderLineRealizations with an obvious relationships.
I want to return some information about orders with an additional column that represents existence of a realization of any line for given group.
Simplified query looks like this:
SELECT 
Orders.Id,
SUM(OrderLines.Quantity) AS TotalAmount,
-- Is there a realization?
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN OrderLines ON OrderId = Orders.Id
GROUP BY Orders.Id -- some additional grouping

I tried:
SELECT 
Orders.Id,
SUM(OrderLines.Quantity) AS TotalAmount,
CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM OrderLineRealizations
                 WHERE OrderLineId IN (OrderLines.Id))
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END AS RealizationExists
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN OrderLines ON OrderId = Orders.Id
GROUP BY Orders.Id

But it's not allowed to use IN like this.
I also cannot use Left Join for realizations, because then I get an incorrect TotalAmount.
Result I want to achieve:
Orders
- - - -
Id
1
2

OrderLines
- - - -
Id | OrderId | Quantity
1  | 1       | 10 
2  | 1       | 15
3  | 2       | 11

OrderLineRealizations
- - - -
Id | OrderLineId |
1  | 1           |

Result
- - - -
OrderId | TotalAmount | RealizationExists
1       | 25          | 1
2       | 11          | 0

What can I write a query to get an expected result?

When joining messes up group by aggregation, you can do the GROUP BY in a subquery before joining.

SELECT 
  Id,
  SUM(Quantity) AS TotalAmount,
  max(RealizationExists) as RealizationExists
from ( 
    SELECT 
      Orders.Id,
      OrderLines.Quantity, 
      CASE
        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM OrderLineRealizations olr 
                     where olr.OrderLineId = OrderLines.Id)
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END as RealizationExists
    FROM Orders
    INNER JOIN OrderLines ON OrderId = Orders.Id
) tmp
group by id;

Here is DBFiddle demo

Seems like you read the question better than I did. Upvoted.

Thank you, just tested it, works perfect.

The safe way is to GROUP BY and aggregate in a derived table before joining:
SELECT 
      Orders.Id,
      ol.TotalAmount,
      CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM OrderLineRealizations olr 
                        where olr.OrderLineId = ol.OrderId) THEN 1
           ELSE 0
      END as RealizationExists
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN (select OrderId, sum(Quantity) AS TotalAmount
            from OrderLines
            GROUP BY OrderId) ol ON ol.OrderId = Orders.Id

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/8yejSpeu (based on @Cetin Basoz' fiddle, thanks!)

The one I provided was already safe :)

@CetinBasoz, true. However, the advice to GROUP BY first, then JOIN, is easy to remember and never fails.

Good advise, never thought about it, thank you!

Yes, that is I generally do. They are very interchangeable sometimes :)

Inspired by Cetin Bazos solution I found another more simple solution (Updated thanks to @siggemannen coment):
SELECT O.Id, SUM(L.Quantity) AS TotalAmount, MAX(CASE WHEN Tmp.OrderLineId IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS RealizationExists
FROM Orders O
INNER JOIN OrderLines L ON L.OrderId = O.Id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT R.OrderLineId FROM OrderLineRealizations R
) Tmp ON Tmp.OrderLineId = L.Id
GROUP BY O.Id

https://dbfiddle.uk/-NucW1xG

That won't work because because SELECT TOP 1 R.OrderLineId, R.Id FROM OrderLineRealizations R doesn't correlate to anything and will always select a random row from OrderLineRealizations, try adding some more OrderLineRealizations in your test to see how it works

You are right, thanks for pointing out

I'd delete this answer, the accepted one is the correct way

Why? Updated version is also correct, more simple and doesn't require duplication of column names in sub query. What is so wrong about having multiple solution for a question?

Because it will perform much worse probably, and also, someone else below already wrote the same thing.


Would be good if you explain why it's much worse 2) If you will take a close look at the edit time of the solution below, you will notice, that the person below copied my query one hour after me.


Thanks for table and data ready @cetin basoz . Left join should do the work.
with _orderlines as (
    select 
    sum(quantity) qty
    ,orderid 
from orderlines group by orderid
    )
select
    o.id
    ,ol.qty
    ,coalesce(orderlineid,0,1) 
from orders o
inner join _orderlines ol on o.id=ol.orderid
left join OrderLineRealizations olr on olr.orderlineid=o.id;

